# How to return the same result from str.scan and str.match in Ruby using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, match

I have a method to capture the extension as a group using a regex:

```
def test(str)

  word_match = str.match(/\.(\w*)/)

  word_scan = str.scan(/\.(\w*)/)

  puts word_match, word_scan

end

test("test.rb")
```

So it will return:

```
.rb
rb
```

Why would I get a different answer?

Comment: Don't reinvent a wheel. Ruby has well-tested code to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `match` and `scan` return different objects. `match` returns either a `MatchData` object or a `String` while `scan` returns an `Array`. You can see this by calling the `class` method on your variables

```
puts word_match.class # => MatchData
puts word_scan.class  # => Array
```

If you take a look at the `to_s` method on `MatchData` you'll notice it returns the entire matched string, rather than the captures. If you wanted just the captures you could use the `captures` method.

```
puts word_match.captures # => "rb"
puts word_match.captures.class # => Array
```

If you were to pass a block to the `match` method you would get a string back with similar results to the `scan` method.

```
word_match = str.match(/\.(\w*)/) { |m| m.captures } # => [["rb"]]
puts word_scan.inspect  #=> ["rb"]
puts word_match #=> "rb
```

More information on these methods and how they work can be found in the [ruby-doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) for the String class.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your own code for this, take advantage of Ruby's own built-in code:

```
File.extname("test.rb")         # => ".rb"
File.extname("a/b/d/test.rb")   # => ".rb"
File.extname(".a/b/d/test.rb")  # => ".rb"
File.extname("foo.")            # => "."
File.extname("test")            # => ""
File.extname(".profile")        # => ""
File.extname(".profile.sh")     # => ".sh"
```

You're missing some cases. Compare the above to the output of your attempts:

```
fnames = %w[
  test.rb
  a/b/d/test.rb
  .a/b/d/test.rb
  foo.
  test
  .profile
  .profile.sh
]

fnames.map { |fn|
  fn.match(/\.(\w*)/).to_s 
}
# => [".rb", ".rb", ".a", ".", "", ".profile", ".profile"]

fnames.map { |fn|
  fn.scan(/\.(\w*)/).to_s  
}
# => ["[[\"rb\"]]",
#     "[[\"rb\"]]",
#     "[[\"a\"], [\"rb\"]]",
#     "[[\"\"]]",
#     "[]",
#     "[[\"profile\"]]",
#     "[[\"profile\"], [\"sh\"]]"]
```

The documentation for [File.extname](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html#method-c-extname) says:

> Returns the extension (the portion of file name in `path` starting from the last period).
>
> If `path` is a dotfile, or starts with a period, then the starting dot is not dealt with the start of the extension.
>
> An empty string will also be returned when the period is the last character in `path`.
>
> On Windows, trailing dots are truncated.

The [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html) class has many more useful methods to pick apart filenames. There's also the [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) class which is very useful for similar things.